# Using ctypes to call C++ function with pointer args

Tags: python, c++, numpy, ctypes

Some background (might not be directly related to the problem): I need to perform an efficient matrix multiplication with a known sparsity.
Because it's sparse, using normal matrix multiplication is wasteful, and because it's a known sparsity I can implement it in an efficient way rather than using sparse libraries.

I have implemented my function in C++

```
void SparsePrecisionMult(double *Q, double *X, double *out, const int dim, const int markov, const int n);
```

This is the "wrapper":

```
import ctypes
_SPMlib = ctypes.CDLL('./SparsePrecisionMult.so')
_SPMlib.SparsePrecisionMult.argtypes = (ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double),
                                        ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int)

def sparse_precision_mult(Q, X, out, markov_blanket_size):
    global _SPM
    m, d = X.shape
    _SPMlib.SparsePrecisionMult(Q.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)),
                                X.T.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)),
                                out.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)),
                                d, markov_blanket_size, m)
```

And this is how i called it:

```
patch_size = 3
markov_blanket = 3

C = np.eye(9)
X = np.array(range(0, 27, 1)).reshape(3, 9)

out = np.zeros([3, 9])

sparse_precision_mult(C.astype(np.float64), X.astype(np.float64), out.astype(np.float64), 3)

print(out)
```

This test should result in out=X.
A version of this test written in C performs well.
I get out = zeros. So my guess is that somehow the memory isn't shared and being copied.
I don't want duplications of data on my RAM (this function will be used on high dimension matrices). So how can I solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`astype` creates a copy of an array. Therefore the `out.astype(np.float64)` parameter gives a copy to `sparse_precision_mult` which is modified and then thrown away. Original `out` isn't modified.

Create `out` with type `np.float64` and (if necessary) convert after function call.

If possible you should create all parameters with the type needed for the function call initially to avoid the copying by `astype`.

`astype` has a parameter `copy` which can be set to `False` to avoid unnecessary copies but it is better to be sure that a copy is/isn't needed than relying on that.